# Unable to debug a fork() call properly

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, gdb, fork

```
int spawn( char* program, char** args) {

    pid_t child_pid;

    child_pid = fork(); 

    if( child_pid!= 0) {  // so this returns if the forking fails? Why would a fork fail?
        return (int)child_pid;
    }

    else {
        execvp(program, args);

        return (int)child_pid;
    }
}
```

I have the following code I am trying to debug. The problem is, when the parent calls it the child_pid value in my watchlist is some big number (bigger than zero) but the program itself does go in the else block. 
I want to see how it goes in that else block buy my gdb debugger seems to stop after the child_pid returns its big number

Comment: Have you read the `man` page for `fork`? Specifically about the return values and error codes?

Comment: `fork()` returns `0` in the child process, `>0` in the parent's process, or `-1` if there's an error (it could fail if you have reached your process limit).

Comment: gdb only focuses on one process at a time. Type `set follow-fork-mode child` before you run the program to have gdb switch to the child rather than stay with the parent.

Comment: Note that you'll have problems if the `execvp()` call fails.  You should probably call `exit()` (or `_exit()`), probably after reporting the appropriate error.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick thank you. That was the answer I was looking for